# Spacy - How to add an item in the StringStore when training a new model via the CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, spacy-3

I try to train a a spacy model using the CLI. The model is defined in a cfg and I try to train it on a DocBin. When the DocBin does not contain marked named entities it works fine. When I add named entities in the DocBin it crashes and it seems to be due to the label of the ent (not contained in vocab).

I am trying to train a new spacy model using the CLI interface. I generated a cfg file using spacy's webtool and I rely on the model "fr_core_news_lg" (my text is in French). I trained the model on test marked DocBin. It works fine and I can see that the model properly learned by importing it afterwards in a python script. All good up to now.

The issue is here : when I train the model on a DocBin containing named entities (ent) with custom labels the model crashes in very early training. The error message I get is:

```
ValueError: [E084] Error assigning label ID 17808484808209568037 to span: not in StringStore.
```

I checked the string store of the model that has been used to mark the DocBin and "17808484808209568037" is the hash corresponding to "cn_fraction".  cn_fraction is not in the text... this the label given to specific named entities.

I assume that in order to resolve this I would need to add the word cn_fraction to the string store of the model I train. This model is not defined in python, it is generated by the cfg file. What is the best way to do this ?